# how compiler auto vectorization works?

Tags: compilation

Different architectures have their own SIMD instruction extentions and even for x86 intel and amd have different extentions how compilers manage this, in order to create a machine code which leverage SIMD extensions ?

Comment: Programmers manage it by providing various flags to the compiler, like [MSDN: Visual Studio → C++ Compiler Options → /arch (x86)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx), so that compiler can choose which set of features to use. Language runtime can later opt to load architecture-specific library after detecting the available hardware. Specify **more exactly** what you need to know and why

Comment: Thanks for your reply
According to the book "Professional assembly language" even for x86 arch some amd cpus doas not support SSE extentions, instead other kind of SIMD instructions developed by amd which are not software compatible with intel SIMD extentions
My question is how compiler handles this incompatibilities ?

Comment: It's almost like: programmer sets some options, compiler sets some `#define` values and the rest is up to the standard compiling-linking-runtime library. To find out **exactly** how does your compiler do it: pick a very `SIMD`-specific word (e.g. some from the `SSE3 INSTRUCTIONS` chapter from [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and full-text search this word through the source codes of your C(++) compiler's runtime library (including assembly language source files)